# From which set is this bag?

Tags: set-identification

Which set is this bag of pieces from?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Based on the presence of the White Plate 8x8 with cut corner, the Black Plate 10x10 with cut corner without center studs, and the engine nacelles in Dark Bluish Gray, this is set [31066 Space Shuttle Explorer](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=31066-1).

[image]